# Every locally free sheaf on $P_k^n$ is sum of twisted structural sheafs

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I read in Hartshorne III.7.1 that every locally free sheaf of $P_k^n$ (where $k$ - field) is direct sum of $\mathcal{O}_{P_k^n}(q)$ but I don't understand why. Hope for your help!

Comment: It is not true!

Comment: What about locally free of finite rank?

Comment: It is true for $n=1$, but not otherwise. Take for example the cotangent sheaf on $\mathbb P^2$. Using the Euler sequence one finds that $H^1(\mathbb P^2, \Omega_{\mathbb P^2}^1)=\mathbb C$. But that is impossible if $\Omega_{\mathbb P^2}^1$ were a direct sum of line bundles (they all have zero cohomology $H^1$).

Comment: Where did you read that? Please give a direct quote and specific citation.

Comment: Sorry, it was little misunderstanding of proof III.7.3, but now it's clear.